# Why is spark .sparkStaging folder under hdfs when running spark on yarn in local machine?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

i am trying to figure out why my spark .sparkStaging folder default to be under  /user/name/ folder on my local hdfs ? I never set the working directory for spark at all. Hence why and how do i get this set with hdfs ? what configuration sets the default for that. I checked in spark environement in the UI Tab, and the config of yarn, and i can't see anything that sets that. Can someone give me a hint on that ?

Comment: [_`spark.yarn.stagingDir` Default: Current user's home directory in the filesystem_](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html)

Comment: How does that end up in hdfs ? Is there something that says that when you run on yarn, your local file system is automatically hdfs ? I could not find any documentation about that. Do you have anything on it ?

Comment: `core-site.xml` -> `fs.defaultFS`?

Comment: Yes saw that. But nothing says that this is suppose to be used to define the user home directory for yarn ? What I mean is in term of doc, I don’t find anything explicitly explaining those things.